# Rounding off the numbers to four digit after decimal

Tags: python, pandas

I am normalising my data and want to finally store a rounded of 4 digit number after decimal.

The below statement gives me a normalised result but how do I round of every number to 4 digit number after decimal.

```
df_new = df.loc[:,"pos_score":"neg_sub_score"].div(100, axis=0)
```

Original : `18.685714285714287`

After normalisation: `.1868` (desired)

After normalisation: `.18685714285714287` (current)

Comment: `df.loc[:,"pos_score":"neg_sub_score"].div(100, axis=0).round(4)` ??

Comment: I am familiar with round() but I'll try this way!

Comment: Well you can always do `float('0.{}0000'.format(str(df_new*100))[:4])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need floor values multiple by `100`, convert to integers and divide by `10000`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pos_score':[18.68577,18.685714],
                   'neg_sub_score':[10.23, 12.536]})
print (df)
   pos_score  neg_sub_score
0  18.685770         10.230
1  18.685714         12.536

df_new1 = df.loc[:,"pos_score":"neg_sub_score"].mul(100).astype(int).div(10000)
print (df_new1)
   pos_score  neg_sub_score
0     0.1868         0.1023
1     0.1868         0.1253
```

But if need round values add [`DataFrame.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html), but different output:

```
df_new2 = df.loc[:,"pos_score":"neg_sub_score"].div(100).round(4)
print (df_new2)
   pos_score  neg_sub_score
0     0.1869         0.1023
1     0.1869         0.1254
```